# Oracle view invalid identifier

Tags: database, oracle, view, oracle11g

I have to implement

> Create a view that shows the total rental income per movie in the database

So I did

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW MovieIncome AS SELECT s.movie_copy_id, SUM(S.PRICE)
AS Income FROM TRANSACTIONS s
left OUTER JOIN MOVIE_COPIES ON MOVIE_COPIES.movie_copy_id = s.movie_copy_id
left OUTER JOIN MOVIES ON MOVIES.ID = MOVIE_COPIES.MOVIE_copy_id
WHERE MOVIES.ID = MOVIE_COPIES.MOVIE_copy_id
GROUP BY MOVIES.NAME;
```

Transactions table have: transaction_id, movie_copy_id, customer_id, price. 
MOVIE_COPIES table have: type, store_id, movie_copy_id, movie_number
MOVIES table have: id, name, minutes.

But Oracle drops me

`ORA-00904: "S"."MOVIE_COPY_ID": invalid identifier`

My friend has same task, and his columns are different name, but same purpose and works fine, for me it doesn't.

Comment: Are you sure you show us correct statement? There is no Transaction_ID in statement

Comment: (fixed) Yes, I have transaction_id in Transactions table :/

Comment: But it is not in your statement, so I don't think this statement and exeption are correlated

Comment: you are right, I was trying different columns, fixed now

Comment: Please edit your question and include the definition (column names and data types) for the tables involved in this query. Thanks.

Comment: The code and message still don't match; the code references transactions_id but the error doesn't have the 's'.

Comment: @AlexPoole it has before transactions_id

Comment: pls do a   desc table_name of the tables that are you  using, that would give clarity on the table structure

Answer (score 0):

The issues I could see are:

1. That you got the wrong column in the group by (it should be the non-aggregated columns used in the select).
2. That you specify the join condition in a where clause too which is not needed
3. That the join between the `movies` and `movie_copies` table probably should be on `movies.id = movie_copies.movie_number` (this is just a guess though).

This code works:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW MovieIncome AS 
SELECT s.movie_copy_id, MOVIES.NAME, SUM(S.PRICE) AS Income 
FROM TRANSACTIONS s
LEFT OUTER JOIN MOVIE_COPIES ON MOVIE_COPIES.movie_copy_id = s.movie_copy_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN MOVIES ON MOVIES.ID = MOVIE_COPIES.movie_number
GROUP BY s.movie_copy_id, MOVIES.NAME;
```

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d53cfb/1) showing it in action.

Perhaps the query should be using the movies table as source though and left join the other tables or possibly use inner joins instead as it should be safe to assume that any row in the transactions table has to have a relation to the movie_copies table.

So maybe what you want is something like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW MovieIncome AS 
SELECT MOVIE_COPIES.movie_copy_id, MOVIES.NAME, COALESCE(SUM(S.PRICE),0) AS Income 
FROM MOVIES
LEFT OUTER JOIN MOVIE_COPIES ON MOVIES.ID = MOVIE_COPIES.movie_number
LEFT OUTER JOIN TRANSACTIONS s ON MOVIE_COPIES.movie_copy_id = s.movie_copy_id
GROUP BY MOVIE_COPIES.movie_copy_id, MOVIES.NAME;
```

This would return 0 for movies for which no copies have been rented out at all.

Comment: I don't need return of 0, I need to return tolal price of each movie, I check that name would be same as copy, with transaction copy.

Comment: The first code you wrote, doesnt work for me anyway, still receiving same problem.

Comment: @RenatasValatka If you look at the SQL Fiddle I linked, is anything different in your code apart from data types? If the column names are like you described and the query text is the same it should work, just as the fiddle shows.

Comment: @RenatasValatka So the code is identical but you get the error anyway? That sounds really odd.